# Predicting a continuous y with a categorical bin at upper bound

Tags: r, machine-learning, categorical-data, python, predictive-models

I have a problem where I'm asked to predict a continuous variable m, and present predictions binned in the following way:

- m in 0-7
- m in 8-16
- m in 17-24
- m in 25+

In my data, m is truncated at 25; m=25 might really represent an underlying reality of m=37 or 100 or 26 or whatever. Hence a bin for '25+'.

It seems to me the best way to handle this is to stack two predictors:

- A first-level classifier to predict True/False on whether m>25.

  - if I predict True for that question, predict m is in '25+' bin
  - if I predict False for that question...

    - Fit a second-level predictor to predict m as a continuous variable (1-24)

This approach seems to make sense to me. The issue I'm running into is for the following scenario:

For records where my first-level classifier incorrectly predicts m is <25, I move to the continuous predictor. But what should I use as the true-label for that record? I want predictions for this 2nd level to be in [1-24]. I could call it 25, but in my data the difference between '24' and '25' is a categorical difference, not the same as the difference between 22 and 23 for example. I could call the label 30, to try and reflect that 'much larger than 23' kinda effect, but 30 seems arbitrary.

Obviously my first-level T/F classifier won't be perfect, so I have to make some decision on the y/labels for this second-level continuous predictor where true-y is really a categorical '25+'.

What I've settled on for now is:

- just set y=30 when fitting that second level model. any rows that get predicted at anything >24 will get predicted as bin 25+. Any number <=24 would be binned in the obvious way.
- This '30' number is really a hyperparameter of this second-level model, so I can cross-validate and tune that. (I'm using python/sklearn/gridsearchCV for hyperparam tuning, but could use r/caret as well)

Anyway, I think all this is reasonable, but if anyone has any perspective on best practices for predicting a continuous variable where there's sort an 'upper bound category' at the top, I'd be interested. Tried plenty of googling but haven't found what I'm looking for.

Comment: The technical term for this kind of variable is worth knowing: it's not "truncation" but (right) *censoring*.  Truncation amounts to throwing away any observations where $m \ge 25$, whereas censoring consists of keeping them but labeling them only as $25+$.  Searching for methods of prediction of censored responses might give you some ideas.

Comment: hey thanks whuber that's very helpful. will revisit my lit search tonight. EDIT: and thanks for the follow-up suggestion below

Comment: I should also have mentioned that one (seemingly unlikely) place to search is "survival analysis," because this field routinely has to cope with right-censored data.

Comment: Thanks again whuber. survival analysis is exactly what I was looking for with this problem.